# How to combine two columns in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

What commands to combine column1 and column2 relative to the content and then remove column2?
In addition, if both columns contain something, consider the content of column1 as the first choice.
It's about SQLite. Please note that these are permanent changes to the database and column layout, not a JOIN for SELECT.

Input SQLite database:

```
|column1 | column2 |column_a|
|========|=========|========|
|"test"  |         |1       |
|"test2" |"test3"  |2       |
|        |"xxx"    |3       |
```

Pseudocode:

column1 = column1 + column2
column2.delete()

Wyjściowa baza SQLite:

```
|column1 |column_a|
|========|========|
|"test"  |1       |
|"test2" |2       |
|"xxx"   |3       |
```

Comment: Is this a question about `SELECT` or `UPDATE`. Do you require `column2` to be dropped from the table (i.e. deleted) or you just do not require it to appear in a `SELECT`?

Comment: [ask] https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Answer (score 2):

This type of work needs to be done in a few steps.

1. Use the query from @Tim Biegeleisen to create a new table. Say `tab_dev` (To be safe, you should use `CREATE TABLE` and then `INSERT INTO` to make sure column types, constraint...etc are created to specs).

```
create table tab_dev
as
select COALESCE(column1, column2) as column1,
       columna
  from tab_prod;
```

At this moment, you should have the old version `tab_prod` and new version `tab_dev`. Carefully review the new table against the old one before proceed to next step.

2. Rename the old table to some backup table first (DO NOT DELETE it at this moment).

```
alter table tab_prod rename to tab_prod_backup;
```

3. Now the old version table's name is available, so rename the new version `tab_dev` to `tab_prod`.

```
alter table tab_dev rename to tab_prod;
```

4. Carefully verify and validate data in `tab_prod` if everything goes as planned.  Delete the backup table `tab_prod_backup` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `COALESCE()` here:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(column1, column2) AS column1,
       column_a
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the table name is `myTable`. Here's the DDL for your question:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable(column1, column2, column_a);
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES("test", null, 1);
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES("test2", "test3", 2);
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(null, "xxx", 3);
```

The other answers suggest `COALESCE` which seems to be a function that's perfect for your use case. Alternatively, if you are looking to customize the conditional and return values, consider using `CASE`, e.g.

```sql
SELECT (CASE WHEN column1 is NULL THEN column2 ELSE column1 END) as column1,
       column_a
FROM   myTable;
```